# How do you open .txt file containing matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am currently working on the project and have a difficulty to open .txt file in Matlab.
This .txt file contains rainfall radar data in matrix (numbers) form, [m,n] = [360,90].
Below is the data I am having trouble with.

---

```
Projection Metadata:

Radar number 54

Number of radials in scan           360

Number of range bins in scan        90

Starting range                      127500.000000

Maximum range                       150000.000000

Azimuth of first radial             -0.500000

Azimuth of last radial              359.500000

Range bin size                      250.000

Separation between radials          1.000

Projection                          POLAR

Units                               METRES DEGREES

Spheroid                            GRS80

Parameters :

Latitude of radar (degrees)         -34.017000

Longitude of radar (degrees)        151.230000

Beam elevation angle (0 for CAPPI)  0.000

Scan metadata :

Time (seconds since 01/01/1970)     973199701

Time (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss)          02/11/2000 21:15:01

Time zone (seconds ahead of UTC)    0

Time zone (hours ahead of UTC)      +0.0

Data type flag                      9

Data type                           Reflectivity

Data units                          dBZ

Not forecast data

Not simulated data

Scan data :

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ..>1 

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ....

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ....

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ....

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ....

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ....

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ....

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ....

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ..>360

.         .          .         .         .        .         .          .        .          .

.         .          .         .         .        .         .          .        .          .

.         .          .         .         .        .         .          .        .          .

.       .          .         .         .        .         .          .        .          90

End of scan data.
```

As you can see the first 29 text lines as well as the last text line need to be skipped.

I would be really appreciated if anybody can help me open up this file in Matlab in the form of

matrix [row,column] = [360,90].

Thank you very much for your time.

Regards,
NadeaR

Answer (score 2):

You can use MATLAB's `importdata` function, which will read in and save the file in two fields: a cell array 'textdata' for the header and a matrix 'data' for the numerical data that follows.

```
input = importdata('datafile.txt', ' ', 29)
```

The arguments in this example are the input file name, a space as the delimiter character, and the number of header lines.

The 360x90 matrix would then be stored as `input.data`.

You can use a variable as the header-length argument if the number of header lines varies but is known for each file. If you don't know how many header lines to expect, you could do some fancy footwork in MATLAB to parse the .txt file but at that point, I would pre-process the .txt file with sed or perl, etc. and then read in the numerical portion in MATLAB, instead.