# how to read a matrix from a text file in matlab

Tags: matlab, transpose

I have a text file which has `500 columns` and `500 rows`, of numerical(integer) values . Every element in the row is separated by a tab. I want to read this file as a matrix in `matlab`. Example(my text file is like this):

```
 1 2 2 1 1 2 
 0 0 0 1 2 0
 1 2 2 1 1 2 
 0 0 0 1 2 0
```

And after reading this text file as a matrix (`a[]`) in matlab I want to do `transpose`.
Help me.

Comment: Have you tired `load` with `-ascii` option?

Comment: Quite similar entry here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730562/how-do-you-open-txt-file-containing-matrix-in-matlab?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You can use `importdata`.
Something like:

```
filename = 'myfile01.txt';
delimiterIn = '\t';
headerlinesIn = 1;
A = importdata(filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
A_trans = A';
```

You can skip headerlines if your file does not have any haeder.. (It is the number of lines before the actual data starts)

Taken from Matlab documentation, [improtdata](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired `load` with `-ascii` option?
For example

```
 a = load('myfile.txt', '-ascii'); % read the data
 a = a.'; %' transpose
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% Pre-allocate matrix
Nrow=500; Ncol=500;
a = zeros(Nrow,Ncol);
% Read file
fid = fopen('yourfile.txt','r');
for i:1:Nrow
   a(i,:) = cell2mat(textscan(fid,repmat('%d ',Ncol));
end
fclose(fid); 
% Trasnspose matrix
a_trans = a.';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
yourVariable = importdata('yourFile.txt')';
%Loads data from file, transposes it and stores it into 'yourVariable'.
```